# Android Studio - App doesn't cover Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I am new to android studio and I have been creating a few projects, learning different concepts. I am now making my first application and I've noticed that when I launch all my applications on the emulator, the content doesn't completely cover the application. In my XML, the activity is centered in the app, but on the emulator everything's strangely shifted to the left.

I have posted images below to explain what I am talking about. I was wondering if this is normal, or am I doing something wrong. Since I spent a lot of time laying out the XML activity the way I desire, and then it is displayed awful on the emulator.

This is the Login Page, notice how centered and laid out all the views are.

[image]

This is the application launched on the emulator. Notice how the content is constrained, and kind of squeezed and pushed to the top left corner.

How do I fix this issue?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/barbell_background"
android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
tools:context=".Login">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/AppLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="118dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
    android:maxHeight="150dp"
    android:maxWidth="150dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/fitness_logo_white"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LoginUsernameLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/AppLogo">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:minWidth="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/user_icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/LoginUsernameInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="240dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LoginPasswordLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/AppLogo">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:minWidth="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/password_icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/LoginPasswordInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="240dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/SignInButton"
    android:layout_width="297dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:width="250dp"
    android:height="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/login_button_design"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/sign_in"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/LoginPasswordLayout" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SignInButton">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/don_t_have_an_account"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/SignUp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="@string/sign_up" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/DB_Display_Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="92dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/signup_button_design"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Display Login Database"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2" />


 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have set all the necessary constraint for all the view. that is why they are getting shifted to the 0,0(top left) location of the screen. 
Could you post the whole xml code?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
tools:context=".Main2Activity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/AppLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="118dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
    android:maxHeight="150dp"
    android:maxWidth="150dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="118dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LoginUsernameLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/AppLogo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:minWidth="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/user_icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/LoginUsernameInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="240dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LoginPasswordLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/LoginUsernameLayout"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:minWidth="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/password_icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/LoginPasswordInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="240dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/SignInButton"
    android:layout_width="297dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:width="250dp"
    android:height="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/login_button_design"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/sign_in"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/LoginPasswordLayout"
    android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SignInButton"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.154">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/don_t_have_an_account"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/SignUp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="@string/sign_up" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/DB_Display_Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="92dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/signup_button_design"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Display Login Database"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="92dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.13"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.029"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hey Chandan, I just added my XML code for the activity

Comment: You didn't set left and right constraints for any View. I am posting it after editing it. Hope it should work now. Position Views accordingly i just set constraints.

Comment: I copied your code, but nothing really changed. It's still displayed very similar to the image I posted above.

Comment: But it's perfectly working on my android phone. Have you tried it on your android device?

Comment: No I've only been testing it on my emulator

Comment: Its working fine on real device. you can try on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

You using hard coded values for margins, it will not work on differente resolutions from the one you created it for. You need to use relative sizes for width/height (wrap_content/match_parent) and use gravity to anchor childs relative to its parent (center, left, right, center_horizontal, center_vertical).

margins are used only to add space between views not for centering.

Once you do all this your same screen will work on different screen sizes.

Comment: Am I not correctly using wrap_content, and match_parent? I am also using gravity to center within its parent view. In this particular xml code, you can see I have used gravity on my buttons and used wrap_content for layout height and width. I am incorrectly misusing them?

Comment: The following line: android:layout_marginStart="118dp" will works only on the screen resolution you wrote it for (and similar ones) thats the component you have to centralize with relative constraints instead.

Comment: are relative constraints, layout constraints? Could you give me an example of a relative constraint.

Comment: using layout_gravity="center" for example will make the view centered relatively to its parent

Comment: Nothing happens